# Eigenspaces of outer product

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $A$ = $v$$v^T$, which is basically the outer product. We want to find the eigenspaces of $A$ and eigenspaces of $aI + bA$.

For the eigenspaces of $A$, I got that the eigenvalues are $0$ and $||v||$, so the eigenspaces are $Ker(A)$ and $Ker(A - ||v||I)$. Is this correct?

How do we find the eigenspaces of $aI + bA$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues are $0$ and $\|v\|^2$, not $\|v\|$. To see this,
$$Av = vv^\top v = (v^\top v)v = \|v\|^2 v.$$

As for the eigenspaces, note first that $0$ has multiplicity $n - 1$, where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, unless $v = 0$, in which case it has multiplicity $n$. To see this, appeal to the rank-nullity theorem; remember, the nullspace is the eigenspace corresponding to $0$.

Again, assuming $v \neq 0$, the remaining eigenspace must be $1$-dimensional. Since $v \neq 0$ is an eigenvector by the above argument, we get that $E_{\|v\|^2} = \operatorname{span}(v)$.

Since the matrix is symmetric, the remaining eigenspace $E_0$ must be orthogonal to this eigenspace $E_{\|v\|^2}$, and be of dimension $n - 1$, which implies that
$$E_0 = (E_{\|v\|^2})^\perp = \{v\}^\perp.$$

The eigenspaces of $aI + bA$ are the same provided $b \neq 0$, as Eric points out, and is indeed easy to check. When $b = 0$ (or $v = 0$), there is only one eigenspace: $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Every vector is an eigenvector of $I$ for the eigenvalue $1$, so for any matrix $M$, the eigenspaces of $M$ and $aI+M$ are the same. This shouldn't be too hard for you to show and with that you are essentially done.

Your eigenvalue, eigenvector pairs are almost correct for the first part (although there are nicer ways to write the second one. Is $v$ an eigenvector?). Theo points out the correction.

I also failed to consider the $b=0$ case which Theo pointed out, so I'd say his answer is a bit more complete.

Comment: I get that every vector is an eigenvector of I for the eigenvalue 1, but how does this imply that eigenspaces of M and $aI + M$ are the same? Also, for the nicer way to put it, is it something like $Ker(A)^{\perp}$

Comment: $Ker(A)^\perp$ works, but still we can go even simpler with just $\mathrm{span} (v)$. For showing the eigenspaces of $M$ and $aI+M$ are the same, first show that if $u$ is an eigenvector of $M$ then it is an eigenvector of $aI+M$. Now what is  the corresponding eigenvalue?